# Recommend Books Containing Algebra Problems with Answers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, book-recommendation

I'm a Medical Intern.

I like my job but i'm not crazy about it.

I Always Liked math at High School.

Please Recommend me Books or eBooks Containing Algebra Problems so i can Play between Shifts.

My Back Ground : It's been years since i solved a Math problem But I do programming (C#, Java) and Game Development (Unity) as a Side Job and my income is good and i can't Remember anything under B+ in Math Class.

P.S : I don't want to learn Algebra with Lectures, I just want to Solve Problems and Learn as I do,

Comment: I recommend Dummit and Foote. It has a lot of algebra problems in it!

Comment: Schaum's outlines or something? Anything will do, basically, at this level.

Comment: Although you've used linear-algebra and abstract-algebra as tags, these are not consistent with the algebra-precalculus tag.  Your background in high school mathematics suggests this last is the most relevant.

Comment: I think you don't mean to have the linear algebra and abstract algebra tags, but am not 100% certain.

Comment: i edited the tags, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unconventional, but why not get the [math gre subject book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0375429727). It has solutions and has a quick background on topics.

Comment: thanks every one,
@TyCobb : i'm going to start with this one, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following sounds like it would be a good fit for what you want. The problems are a little beyond, but not by a lot, the typical level in U.S. high school algebra texts. A nice aspect of the book is that it has separate "answers only" and "detailed solutions" sections. I sometimes used this book for extra credit test problems when I taught college algebra courses.

[**Challenging Problems in Algebra**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486691489) by Alfred S. Posamentier and Charles T. Salkind

Comment: i read the preview on amazon,
seems good,
thank you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked for, but what I recommend you try.

If I imagine myself in your situation I think I'd find algebra problems - even hard ones - boring. Why not try some problems in the category *recreational mathematics*? There's an inexpensive Dover book with a free downloadable solutions manual: http://store.doverpublications.com/0486409171.html .

Lots more links with this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=recreational+mathematics+problems